# fread position cursor does not seem to advance as expected

Tags: c, fread, realloc

I'm trying to dynamically `realloc` memory for a file being read one character at a time. It is not printing the buffer character by character. It looks like the `fread` function is not advancing 1 character at a time.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char *newBuffer;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;

    /* Open file for both reading and writing */ 
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        exit(99); 
    }   

    /* Seek to the beginning of the file */
    fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);
    /* Read into memory and display the buffer as its read */
    while (1) {
        newBuffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, (sizeof(char) * (++count)));
        if (newBuffer) {
            buffer = newBuffer;
            buffer += (count - 1);
            fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
            if (feof(fp)) {
                buffer = newBuffer;
                break;
            }
            buffer = newBuffer;
            printf(" %s\n", buffer);
        } else {
           // realloc failed
           free(buffer);
           exit(1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(newBuffer);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Couple things: (1) your `buffer` / `newBuffer` distinction is confusing; I'd have `buffer` and then a pointer `bufp` to wherever within that buffer I'm reading the next character. (2) You're going to have to temporarily write a '\0' character into the buffer after each character you read so that it will be a proper null-terminated string to print with `printf %s`.

Comment: Why are you reading and reallocating byte by byte? This is probably the least performant way to read a file.

Comment: Also you don't need that `fseek` call; a stream is always positioned at the beginning after opening a file with `fopen`.

Comment: Reading/reallocating a file one character at a time is horribly inefficient. If using `fread` consider reading the entire file at once. See for example [**Is there a way to find the line number of...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868792/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-line-number-of-the-current-line-being-read-from-a-fil/34869983#34869983)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not null terminate the buffer before using it as a string in `printf`, this is a problem.

Note that you can simplify or improve the code in various ways:

- no need to `fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);` after `fopen`, the FILE is already at the starting position.  Note that you interverted the arguments to `fseek`: it should be `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);` but you are lucky `SEEK_SET` is #defined as `0`.
- reading one byte from the file is much simpler with `getc` than `fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, fp);`.  It allows for a simpler and better test for end of file.  Using `feof()` only works in your example because you only attempt to read a single byte.
- no need for the initial `malloc`, set `buffer to`NULL`.`realloc`accepts`NULL`and behaves like`malloc`with such as argument,`free`accepts a`NULL` argument and does nothing.
- do not cast the return value of `malloc`, nor `realloc`.
- `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition: either use `sizeof(*buffer)` or elide the sizeof completely.
- do not parenthesize the `return` expression.
- the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`

Here is a simpler version:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *newBuffer;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int count = 0, c;

    /* Open file for both reading */
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        exit(99); 
    }   

    /* Read into memory and display the buffer read */
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        newBuffer = realloc(buffer, count + 2);
        if (newBuffer) {
            buffer = newBuffer;
            buffer[count++] = c;
            buffer[count] = '\0';
            printf(" %s\n", buffer);
        } else {
            // realloc failed
            fclose(fp);
            free(buffer);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks chqrlie. I didn't realise that their was so many things wrong. I will tick up the answers as soon as Im able to do so.          Quick question, can I use getc to read from a file stream rather than a file?

Comment: You can use `getc` to read a byte from a `FILE*`, called a *stream* in the  C Standard. There is no function to read from a file by just giving the filename, the file needs to be opened as a *stream* by `fopen`.

Comment: I have done but not until I get my reputation up to 15 can I tick up this. I will do as soon as I`m up to 15. I haven`t forgotten your help and it was greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf(" %s\n", buffer);` expects `buffer` to end with a `'\0'` (null) character. Your code doesn't provide the required null.

Comment: Sweet, its working now thanks Steve. As an aside (as David J Malan says!) I intend to read not from a file but a file stream hence the need to read character by character. But thanks again!